# How long must people wait in shul for a minyan?

Tags: mitzvah, shemoneh-esrei, synagogue, minyan, zechut-merit

Shulchan Aruch emphasizes the importance of davening the Amidah with the rest of the tzibbur.

If one is in shul and there are 8 or 9 people, should everyone wait before starting Amidah to see if others may soon come in to form a minyan? How long are they required to wait? Do they need to wait at all, assuming that they will not pass a z'man like last time for Mincha.

Comment: Are you looking for a sourced answer only?

Comment: @user6591 Yes, that would be my preference. An unsourced answer would probably better as a comment.

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/28524

Comment: https://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/minyan/

Comment: If one is obligated to travel 18-24 minutes to pray with a quorum *(see Pri Chodosh, Orach Chayim 163:28 and Biur Halachah ad locum s.v. berichuk; however, cf. Pischei Teshuvah, Yoreh Deah 112:6, quoting Shu”t Beis Yaakov #35, who rules more leniently.)*, one could infer at least as much of a requirement when the entire quorum depends on the waiting (without the added effort of walking. Of course this would assume one is counting as well the amount of time/effort already spent by the most effortful of the present congregants, as well as the certainty that someone will show up in that timeframe

Comment: And of course one should never risk missing the zman tefilah even if one knew someone was coming.

Comment: Also, all things otherwise equal, praying as a group, even without a minyan would still be valuable as "*brov am hadrat melech*" - *the splendor of the King is in the numerousness of the people*.  Though arguably the value of sufficient concentration (kavanna) at an individual's own pace, is more valuable, once there's already no quorum.  (Where there is a quorum - Rav Moshe Feinstein, z''l, says the quorum trumps greater *kavanna* - though I think he would agree that the halachic minimum of kavana [e.g. first blessing of shemoneh esrei] would still trump even a minyan)

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/116370

Comment: I don't think they have to wait at all (and of course it depends on how sure they are that a tenth will come), but MB 53:10 says that they could wait up to half an hour.

Answer (score 1):

after seeing your question I decided to research that question. It doesnt seem so clear to me and it seems to be a bit of a machlokes. "Rama 53:3 writes that a congregation which doesn't have a minyan at yishtabach should wait until they get a minyan. See both Magen Avraham 53:4 and Mishna Brurah 53:9 who mention waiting a half hour. Igrot Moshe OC 3:4 says that a congregation at the end of pesukei dzimrah should wait a little bit for a minyan but should not to wait a long time for a minyan since it causes people to talk and be mevatel torah." Halachipida
This is what halachipedia wrote.

Comment: I hope this answer helps